# iMacros - extract numbers with decimal points?

Tags: imacros

If I have for example $0.00MXN and I want to extract only the 0.00 I tried this code:

```
SET !EXTRACT $0.00MXN
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.replace(/\\D/g,\"\");")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

But it prompts me that 000 has been copied, without the decimal points. And then, when it pastes it in the desired field, it pastes the whole $0.00MXN.

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution for you:

```
SET !EXTRACT $2.3334451MXN
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.trim().replace(/\\$|MXN/g, '');")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

---

Try the following code:

```
SET !EXTRACT $0.00MXN
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.match(/[\\d\\.]+/);")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: Hmmm, no matter the value, for example $5.22MXN it outputs 0.00. Instead of 5.22. Basically, I just want it to strip the $ and the MXN without altering the amount nor limiting the decimal points. There are some amounts that might be 2.3334451 for example.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you so much! God bless :-)